# Axios with query parameter gets empty data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to get data of a single product sales data from database through orders that client make and show it in the form of a chart using [Recharts](https://recharts.org/).

I created many orders of a same product with different dates (as you can see in the end of my question thread) but i still see no data in the `chart`. Anything is missing in my code to show sales data of a single product (that i already have its `ID`) in the `chart`?

Theses are my codes below of order.js (where client can order the product) and product.jsx (where the chart of sales of product exist). Also backend (order.js) tested successfully with postman, There are no errors at all in consols or network tab.

(PS: please consider that i'm new in ReactJs and Javascript, thanks :) )

**Back:**

api/order.js :

```
router.get("/income", verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.query.pid;
    const date = new Date();
    const lastMonth = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1));
    const previousMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1));
    try {
        const income = await Order.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    createdAt: { $gte: previousMonth },
                    ...(productId && {
                        products: { $elemMatch: { productId } }
                    }),
                },
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
                    sales: "$amount",
                },
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$month",
                    total: { $sum: "$sales" },
                },
            },
        ]);
        res.status(200).json(income);
    } 
    //...
});
```

**Front:**

requestMethods.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';
const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user).currentUser.accessToken;

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` }
});
```

product.jsx:

```
//...
import { userRequest } from "../../requestMethods";

export default function Product() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const productId = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
  const [pStats, setPStats] = useState([]);

  const product = useSelector((state) =>
    state.product.products.find((product) => product._id === productId)
  );

  const MONTHS = useMemo(
    () => [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Agu",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
    ],
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const getStats = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("orders/income?pid=" + productId);
        console.log(res.data);                    //this clg shows an empty data array !!
        const list = res.data.sort((a, b) => {
          return a._id - b._id;
        });
        list.map((item) =>
          setPStats((prev) => [
            ...prev,
            { name: MONTHS[item._id - 1], Sales: item.total },
          ])
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getStats();
  }, [productId, MONTHS]);

  return (
    <div className="product">
      //...
      <div className="productTop">
        <div className="productTopLeft">
          <Chart data={pStats} dataKey="Sales" title="Sales Performance" />
        </div>
      //...
```

My tests results:

1. I tested Axios URL using postman with query parameter `?pid` and `get` method (`localhost:5000/api/orders/income?pid=`), it shows list of `id` (months) and `total` sales for each month:

```
[
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "total": 224
  },
  {
    "_id": 7,
    "total": 170
  },
  {
    "_id": 8,
    "total": 200
  }
]
```

From this response, i'm expecting to get a chart with axis x and y, while x = `_id` and y = `total`.

2. `console.log(res.data);` shows empty array! why?

Comment: Look at your request through the "Network" tab in the browser. CORS may be interfering with the request.

Comment: nah, cors was ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries and tests, i fixed my problem by removing `?pid=" + productId` from axios URL.

Query alreay been taken care of in the server API.